# Automate PHP Switch statement

Tags: php

I am generating certain items with PHP. Long story short - I have objects with beautiful tooltips saved into a variables. I have more than 100 items generated. So i have a huge dropdown html select of all the items. When the user picks the desired item, he goes to a Generate button. In the backend, i pick up the response and i want to return the item the customer has selected. I am thinking of a switch statement which corresponds the name value of the html select and i match it with the proper item from my variables. Tested it works pretty well. However, if i want to include all my items this would means hundreds of switch cases. I am fine if Switch is my only viable option but is there any way i can automate the switch cases creation? Otherwise i will need to go and manually write down all the switch cases

```
switch ($helm){
    case "harle":
        $helm = $random_harle;
        break;
    case "eth_harle":
        $helm = $random_harle_eth;
        break;
    case "perfect_harle":
        $helm = $perfect_harle;
        break;
    case "perfect_harle_eth":
        $helm = $perfect_harle_eth;
        break;
    // and a 100+ more of these
    default:
    $helm = "None";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map all your items in an array

```
$myitems = ["harle" => $random_harle, 
  .....
];
```

and then use a

```
foreach ($myitems as $key => $value) 
{ 
    if ($key == $helm) 
       return $value;
}
return "None";
```

This tests the given`$helm` with the `$key`. If there is a match you return `$value`.

After the loop (no match) you can return your default value.

Also, as CBroe suggested, a shorter version would be

```
if (array_key_exists($helm, $myitems))
   return $myitems[$helm];
return "None";
```

Comment: You don’t need to loop over the array yourself, you can just use `isset` or `array_key_exists` to check if an entry for a given key exists.

Comment: give ma sec to try out and see if i can manage to pull it off. Thansk for the quick reponse

Comment: Why `foreach` ?

Comment: just to point out that `if (isset($myitems[$helm])
   return $myitems[$helm];
return "None";` is faster than ***array_key_exists***

Comment: @AlexanderDimitrov Yes it is, however it returns `true` if key exists *and* if the value is not null. In this particular case it makes no difference of course, and the OP may choose to use your suggestion since all his values are defined.

Comment: @DNT you are right, but my comment was just a side note. Anyway probably he will not notice the difference for such small dataset.

Comment: @AlexanderDimitrov True, but a valid and useful comment nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks, it is working with foreach. The shorter version CBroe returns: Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in generate-item.php on line 26

Comment: @Djongov That's because I made a mistake in typing out the `array_key_exists` call. I updated my answer with the correction.